# Como transformar esse json em array

Tags: php

Preciso transformar esse json ( não com todos os campos de fields_atributes) em um array no php para pode alterar os dados facilmente

```
    mutation{
  createCard(
    input: {
      pipe_id: 219739
      fields_attributes: [
        {field_id: "assignee", field_value:[00000, 00001]}
        {field_id: "checklist_vertical", field_value: ["a", "b"]}
        {field_id: "checklist_horizontal", field_value: ["b"]}
        {field_id: "cpf", field_value: "123.456.789-00"}
        {field_id: "cnpj", field_value: "12.345.678/1234-00"}
        {field_id: "date", field_value: "1977-01-20"}
        {field_id: "date_time", field_value: "2017-07-20T21:00:00+00:00"}
        {field_id: "due_date", field_value: "2017-07-20T21:00:00+00:00"}
        {field_id: "currency", field_value: "9500.50"}
        {field_id: "label_select", field_value: [890073, 908006]}
        {field_id: "email", field_value: "rocky.balboa@email.com"}
        {field_id: "number", field_value: 9000}
        {field_id: "short_text", field_value: "Rocky Balboa"}
        {field_id: "long_text", field_value: "It ain’t about how hard you hit. It’s about how hard you can get hit and keep moving forward. It’s how much you can take, and keep moving forward. That’s how winning is done."}
        {field_id: "radio_vertical", field_value: "yes"}
        {field_id: "radio_horizontal", field_value: "no"}
        {field_id: "phone", field_value: "+55 11 1234-5678"}
        {field_id: "select", field_value: "B. Rocky Balboa II"}
        {field_id: "time", field_value: "17:25"}
      ]
      parent_ids: ["2750027"]
    }
  ) {
    card {
      id
      title
    }
  }
}
```

Porem não como fazer quando é assim:

```
        {field_id: "cpf", field_value: "123.456.789-00"}
```

Oque fiz até agora foi isso:

```
$arr = array(
         "mutation" => array(
           "createCard" =>  array(
             "input" => array(
               "pipe_id" => "219739",
               "fields_attributes" => array(
                 "field_id" => "valore",
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ),

 );
```

Caso alguem tenha duvida sobre o JSON, ele vem da seguinte API: [pipefy](https://pipefypipe.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/create-card/createcard(input:-%7Bparams%7D))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Isso não é um** `JSON` e sim o **formato de uma "requisição"** que deve ser usada para criar um card:

> Create card Mutation to create a card, in case of success a query is
>   returned. 
>   Request Body

Na documentação já diz: `Request Body` (traduzindo: Solicitação, pedido, etc.)

---

**Usando os parâmetros para criar um card:**

Desta forma, você usa o método `createCard` para inserir esses parâmetros (como está na [documentação passada](https://pipefypipe.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/create-card)):

`createCard(input: {params})`

---

O **retorno desta requisição**, agora sim será um `JSON`:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createCard": {
      "card": {
        "id": "2762646",
        "title": "Rocky Balboa"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Para transformar o retorno em** `array`:

```
$json = // retorno da criação do card

$json_array = json_decode($json, true);
```

*Documentação*: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)

---

*Para ver o exemplo de requisição e retorno do método "createCard", clique no botão abaixo do exemplo do link que você postou* (ou [aqui](https://pipefypipe.docs.apiary.io/reference/0/show-card/card(id:-card_id))).

Comment: Notei isso depois que postei

Comment: Sem problemas, o importante é que foi resolvido ! :]